# how to list all the entities in NEW state for a UoW

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I would like to list all the entities that are about to be persisted through an `INSERT` wen `flush()`ing , therefore assosiated with a `NEW` state.
Is that possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. `getScheduledEntityInsertions()` returns scheduled entity insertions for UoW object.
So just call `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()`